# How to run Rebol on Freya

Tags: rebol, rebol2

Been trying to run `rebol-view-278-4-2` on [Elementary OS "Freya"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS#0.3_Freya) *(a variant of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)*.

I keep getting this error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libXaw.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I went ahead and tried to install the missing library but to no avail.

Comment: Rebol2 is 32-bit only *(although a 64-bit experimental build of the [old view](http://www.rebol.com/cgi-bin/blog.r?view=0552) was put out recently, though the comments suggest it doesn't necessarily work very well)*.  If your system is 64-bit it is likely that you do not have the 32-bit version of libXaw.  Try getting the `libXaw.i386` package if this is the case.

Comment: Correction: the 64-bit build is not of view, but of core...the comments *ask* for view.

Comment: @HostileFork ,Tried to install libxaw.i386 here is what i'm getting : Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libXaw.i386
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libXaw.i386'

Comment: According to the below you might need a `7` on the libxaw.  Note that for things like not being able to get X-Windows 32-bit compatibility installed, it's not really a programming question... see [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) for any future issues along those lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the steps I took to get R2 core and view working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS "Trusty," so I would imagine that this would also work on Freya:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386
sudo apt-get install libxext6:i386
sudo apt-get install libxaw7:i386
sudo apt-get install libfreetype6:i386
sudo apt-get install xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi
```

(I prefer to keep the package install steps separate in case one of them fails.)

Comment: Thanks a million,everything works perfect.Sorry about the late response,been away